# VBA in Access: How does DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord work?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`

to save but Im not sure how this actually works. Does it save every unsaved change? Or does it save everything no matter if it was changed or not? Or does it only save the current form? Whats about releated unsaved changes in other forms? Or does it function in any other way? Is there any offical documentation to this function?

Comment: Documentation from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-runcommand-method-access) is not that clear, but found this [access-programmers](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?s=a731d8711d9d907c7050c71733921805&p=638978&postcount=3)

Comment: I found this too, but it does not tell what exactly is the "current record" (especially in the context of forms and subforms) and how it saves (everything or just the changes?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It saves the current record of the **active form**. It is the same as clicking on the record selector.

If the current record is not currently being edited (not "Dirty"), then nothing happens.

If you want better control, especially when dealing with subforms, I suggest to use the [`Form.Dirty` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-dirty-property-access) instead. With this you can explicitly address the form you want to save.

To save the current record in a form module (only save when needed):

```
If Me.Dirty Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

To save the record in any form

```
With Forms!myForm
    If .Dirty Then
        .Dirty = False
    End If
End With
```

Or a subform

```
Forms!mainForm!SubFormControl.Form.Dirty = False
```

This is much clearer and better IMO. I have stopped using `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` completely.