# Using spacebar to check a Check Box, perform a DCount(), with focus remaining on the check box?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form with a datasheet subform, where one of the controls is a Check Box (Chk1).

I want it to behave such that: If the check box is checked using mouse click, a DCount(...) on the same Check Box field is performed in the VBA straight away. I have this part working, by navigating away from the record in the Check Box AfterUpdate Sub:

```
Public fromSpace As Boolean

Private Sub Chk1_AfterUpdate()
    If Not fromSpace Then 'mouse click, so it's necessary to fire Form_AfterUpdate by navigating away
        Form_Main.cboSelector.SetFocus
    Else 'Spacebar used with SendKeys so navigating away is not necessary
        fromSpace = False 'reset for next time
    End If
End Sub
```

Then the AfterUpdate of the datasheet subform has the DCount(...)

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    If DCount(...) = x Then 'This DCount looks at the yes/no (Check Box) field in question
        'Do some stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I also want it to behave such that: If the check box is checked using the spacebar key, I would like the same DCount(...) to happen, BUT while keeping focus on the Check Box in the subform (this is so the user can continue to navigate using keyboard).

I actually have it working, but this is using SendKeys ("{F9}")

```
Private Sub chk1_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeySpace Then
        fromSpace = True
        SendKeys ("{F9}") 'This WORKS (DCount(...) is performed, and focus remains on the Check Box). However, I understand using SendKeys is bad practice, so looking for a different solution

        'DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSaveRecord) (I have also tried this, which doesn't work)
        'DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSave) (This doesn't work either)
        
        'also tried doing the DCount(...) here, which doesn't fire until navigating away from the record
        'EDIT: Sorry, I think it does fire, but it doesn't use the new checkbox value in the DCount
    End If
End Sub
```

I also found this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/tysrn7/click_a_button_on_the_ribbon/ (which programmatically does a Ribbon button click), which I tested, and it works, BUT is very slow. There is a 0.5 - 1 second delay every time spacebar is used to check or un-check the Check Box.

Surely there's a way to do this?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: For anyone who is interested, I have elaborated on the code a bit, to show how the SendKeys method is working properly.

Comment: I may have missed something, but to save a record in any form, use `.Dirty = False`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378021/vba-in-access-how-does-docmd-runcommand-accmdsaverecord-work

Comment: Yes I have also tried that already. It still doesn't do the DCount until navigating away from the record. Or if I use .Dirty = false then the DCount in KeyUp, it does the DCount but doesn't use the new CheckBox value that was just changed with the spacebar.

Comment: I am concerned about this question, and I am sorry that you have edited it very seriously and no one has come to answer it. I have to wait until I have more time to come back because Access is a bit of a pain to try out. The questions related to Word, Excel, and PowerPoint are a bit easier. Or would you like to give me a sample to try?

Comment: Hi Oscar. It's not urgent but yes, if you get the chance you could try reproduce it. All you need is a form with a combo box called cbSelector (to move focus to), a datasheet subform based on a table with a yes/no field, a check box on the subform (Control Source as the yes/no field), then just copy my code. Also put this in the subform Load event:
fromSpace = False
You could make the DCount something like:
Debug.Print (DCount("[StuffID]", "Stuff", "[fldYesNo] = true"))
And see if that reports the correct count, which needs to include the new value just entered using the spacebar.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `KeyUp` event at all. Checking/unchecking the checkbox with the Space key triggers the checkbox `AfterUpdate` just the same as clicking it with the mouse.

The following works for me, the calculated number is always updated immediately.

All code is in the datasheet subform, the main form has no code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub chkYesOrNo_AfterUpdate()

    ' Save the record, triggering Form_AfterUpdate() - it doesn't matter if this is done with a mouse click or the space key
    Me.Dirty = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

    Dim n As Long
    
    ' Calculate n
    n = DCount("*", "tblSubform", "[YesOrNo] = -1")
    Debug.Print n
    
    ' Show number in an unbound text box on the main form
    Me.Parent!txtCount.Value = n
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' Show the number on main form load
    Call Form_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

In all cases, the focus stays on the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great. It seems so simple, now am not sure how I managed to get mixed up with it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I've been there. Events triggering each other (or sometimes not), and subforms thrown in, can do that to you.